# Device Passwords and how do they function

Tags: encryption, passwords, device-locking

What happens when I set a password on a device? Does it encrypt everything with my password?

Comment: Depends on the device and the password.  Answer will be different if you're talking about your fitbit or your iphone or your cisco router.

Comment: I am just saying in general, but you can post device-specific

Comment: @GarrisonPendergrass Mark's statement is that there is no general case. The term "device" is a massively broad term that covers pedometers, phones, tablets, routers, thermostats, etc. The answer is simply: whatever the manufacturer programmed it to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically a storage device can do one of three things:

- memorize the password and keep the data unencrypted, but prevent access to anyone not knowing the password. Pro: very easy to do, very quick, no CPU requirements. Con: if the unencrypted memory and the protective logic can be separated (think *external USB enclosure*), then the data is recoverable without need for the password. The "con" might become a "pro" if you want to recover the data after an enclosure failure.
- encrypt the data with the password (rather, from a key derived from the password using suitable expansion functions), *using a suitably secure algorithm* and using it properly. Pro: easy to do, very secure. Also, knowing the algorithm, the data can be recovered after an external drive failure. Con: requires much more CPU, and it is slower than the memory's read *plus* write time. So a 512 GB, 1 gigabyte-per-second device will take over a quarter of an hour to encrypt. Changing the password requires decrypting and reencrypting and can't be done quickly.
- generate a secure key through some suitably iterated, cryptographically strong pseudorandom algorithm, or even a truly random one (e.g. amplifying the electronic noise from a diode or equivalent, debias and feed into a cryptographically secure generator). Encrypt the whole device with this data encryption key (also called DEK). *Then* encrypt the secure key with a key derived from the password, as above, also called Key Encryption Key or KEK. Pro: much faster to change the password (you only need to decrypt and reencrypt the secure key). Con: same CPU requirements, same slowness upon *initial* encryption, and slightly more vulnerable to [non-naive attacks](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2995539/storage-drives/western-digital-self-encrypting-external-hard-disk-drives-have-flaws-that-can-expose-data.html) involving the recovery of the secure key (i.e., after someone has obtained the secure key, *changing the password is useless*). If the DEK is stored on the enclosure, both [enclosure failure](https://community.wd.com/t/wd-my-book-duo-data-forever-lost-if-drive-enclosure-dies/6496) and drive failure will cause data loss; in such cases it's advisable to have a means of exporting and reimporting the DEK. Of course, this must then be stored in a secure location.

What it really **does**, depends on complex marketing and cost factors that have too many unknowns to be easily or definitely solved. *Usually*, cheaper devices will implement the simplest strategy they can get off with. On the other hand, there are now cheap do-it-all chips on the market that make it ridiculously easy to design and market as secure a device as you want for the price of a song. The question becomes then *how* the encryption is actually implemented.

The reason I stressed "using a secure algorithm, properly" is because you could save somewhat on CPU by using a simpler, less expensive encryption such as a XOR scheme, using the same XOR key for all the data (this is called a Vigenère cipher), for example one sector's worth of so-called "worm". This [has been done](http://www.h-online.com/security/features/Enclosed-but-not-encrypted-746199.html) -- **and is absolutely NOT secure**, whatever fantastically secure algorithm is used to generate the "worm". Such a device *could* be theoretically marketed as "employing so-and-so super-secure algorithm" while any moderately competent tinkerer would be able to decrypt the whole disk from scratch in under one hour by looking at the internal storage.

You can (*usually!*) determine whether the device uses a simple DEK or KEK+DEK strategy by simply timing how much does it take to change the password. On external storage devices, you can (again usually) test whether the data is encrypted or not by moving the storage unit into a nonencrypted enclosure, and seeing whether it's still readable. More than that, it usually requires complex and possibly expensive reverse engineering (although if you're lucky, checking out the model numbers of the chips on Google might be enough to determine at least *what* kind of encryption is being used).